# tufte-org-mode: how to set up?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I would very much like to be able to use the following package in my spacemacs environment:

https://github.com/tsdye/tufte-org-mode

Alas, I am still learning how to do things in spacemacs.

My understanding is that this is a package that needs to be installed locally on my spacemacs distribution (I can't just ask for it to be downloaded from melpa).

To that end what is the correct way to do this? Do I for example create a folder:

```
/.emacs.d/private/local/ox-tufte-latex
```

and then deposit the file `ox-tufte-latex.el` in there? (Here, I'm following the suggestions outline in https://blog.lord.geek.nz/2019/04/25/spacemacs-custom-package-for-the-hasty/).

Comment: Are you sure you want to use that? It says: `Deprecated
The Org mode LaTeX exporter can now be configured to produce Tufte LaTeX input. The patch described below is no longer necessary.`

Comment: @NickD How to do that?

Comment: Ok - yes, this concerned me. But basically all I want to do is produce documents in the style given in https://github.com/tsdye/tufte-org-mode. So I download the files in https://github.com/tsdye/tufte-org-mode and navigate to the folder and open "tufte-latex.org". If the exporter is already setup for producing pdfs then I should be able select "org-export-dispatch". At this point I don't see "Export to Tufte Latex" but I do see    "Export to Latex" and if I use that I get the error "org-babel-read: Symbol's function definition is void: jk-org-kwd!".

Comment: Did @crocefisso's answer work?

Comment: @NickD - thanks - I'm giving it a go as indicated below.

Comment: @crocefisso: I have no idea - never tried it.

Comment: @NickD alas tsdye doesn't provide with much information about this... Didn't find much with Google either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `ox-tufte-latex.el` in a directory. Let `PATH` be the path of this directory.

Add this to your init:

```
  (use-package ox-tufte-latex
    :ensure nil
    :init (add-to-list 'load-path "PATH")
    )
```

`use-package` is installed by default in Emacs 29. Below Emacs 29, `use-package` installation is required.

Note: for html exports there is [org-tufte](https://github.com/Zilong-Li/org-tufte)

Comment: Hi crocefisso - I think I follow all of that. Although I guess the above code would have to go in my dotespacemacs/user-init instead (that is how spacemacs is supposed to work, right?). Unfortunately, I'm on emacs 28.2. Can you provide me with basic instructions on how to install use-package (in spacemacs is this something I need to include under dotespacemacs-configuration-layers ?)

Comment: I don't use spacemacs. Maybe use-package is installed by default in spacemacs (check that with `M-x list-packages`). To install packages (let say `use-package`) in Emacs, do `M-x  package-install use-package`

Comment: Partial success!!!! I can see that us-package is already installed. I then put the code you gave me above into the section of the .spacemacs file labelled "user-config". Now when I open the file tufte-latex.org and try the exporter I get a "Export to Tufte Latex" option... great!! However, when I try to export to pdf I still get the error "Symbol's function definition is void: jk-org-kwd". I feel we are almost there...

Comment: I found the solution to the above problem on the github page of the package: https://github.com/tsdye/tufte-org-mode/issues/1 - however, then I run into another issue..."...wrong type argument...". I'm giving up for now.... if anyone ever manages to make progress with this I would love to hear about it.... I'm accepting the answer given by this thread since it essentially solves the problem as originally posed .... even if I am stuck again at a later stage. Thanks!!

Comment: I never used this package, I hope you find someone who can debug you. As @NickD said, I think it would be best to use the native functionality mentioned by tsdye, but unfortunately we don't know how to do that either... You could open an issue on tsdye's Github.